# What is the typescript equivalent for ReasonML's option type?

Tags: typescript, reason, rescript

In ReasonML `option` type is a variant which can either be `Some('a)` or `None`.

How would I model the same thing in typescript?

Comment: technically, `Optional<MyType>` would just be `MyType | null` for example. So, you can do `type Optional<T> = T | null`. However, I don't think that's quite as helpful as an actual optional type -  you probably want something more robust.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think OP means optional properties. An optional *type* is a result that either might be there or not. It is a more explicit version of a `null` which is an absence of value. Depending on the language, there might be better null-safe handling about it where if something returns `None`, you can still chain more operations that resolve as a no-op, rather than having to manually do type checks all the time or adding null guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't have a direct equivalent. What you'd do instead depends a bit on what you're using it for: A property, a function parameter, a variable or function return type...

If you're using it for a property (in an object/interface), you'd probably use [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#optional-parameters-and-properties), for instance:

```
interface Something {
   myProperty?: SomeType;
//           ^−−−−− marks it as optional
}
```

The same notation works for function parameters.

For variables or return types, you might use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) with `undefined` or `null`, e.g.:

```
let example: SomeType | undefined;
// or
let example: SomeType | null = null;
```

The first one says that `example` can be of type `SomeType` or `undefined`, the second say it can be `SomeType` or `null`. (Note the latter needed an initializer, since otherwise `example` would be `undefined`, and that isn't a valid value for `SomeType | null`.)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
export type None = never;

export type Some<A> = A;

export type Option<A> = None | Some<A>
```

If you're interested in functional programming with ts, you could take a look at [fp-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts)

Comment: I like this idea at a high level, but I don't think you want `never` as `None`, since presumably it's possible for the variable/property/return value to have the "none" value -- otherwise you lose the whole point of Optional. I'm not sure what you'd use instead other than `undefined` or `null`, though, which somewhat begs the question of having the type... Usually there's more to an Optional type than this.

Comment: I was thinking about using null as None, but wasn't sure how would OP mark the None value.

Anyway, I left the link to the package I would choose, if I was interested in using monads from fp

Comment: I'd echo the concerns of @T.J.Crowder - I don't think `never` is a good fit here. Usually, you want an `Optional` when you *can* handle either case, so you'd have `getFromDb(id: number): Optional<DbRecord>` and you can more uniformly handle the result as `getFromDb(42)?.name`. This isn't possible with `never` but it *is* if you return `null`. Then again, optional types aren't really about optional chaining - the previous code should return a `Optional<string>` that you can continue operating with without worrying for nulls until you "unwrap" it.